# Class used to assign a variable is different from class used to declare it

Tags: java, class, variable-assignment, declaration

Are the following two versions of "pane" the same in Java?

```
Pane pane1 = new HBox();
HBox pane2 = new HBox();
```

What is the difference between the two and why would you declare pane1 this way?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947

Comment: This sounds like homework. Do you have an idea yourself?

Answer (score 0):

There is a hierarchy of classes. See the Figure below.

In a variable of Pane type you could store a VBox or a HBox for example.

But if you declare the variable as VBox, it can only store a VBox object.

[image]